# Kotlin Channels usage difference between Send and Offer

Tags: kotlin, channel, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-coroutine-channel

Channels have two functions that allow us to send events into it. 
`Send` and `offer`.

I would like to understand better the difference between both.

I have some statements I wanna check are true.

- `Send` is a suspend function. What will make my code(not the thread) wait for it to finish. So it keep running after the event inside `send` was complete/cancelled. OR it will be suspend only until I can queue the event/receive it?
- This means that, if I use `send` from one channel to another, the first channel will be block until the second can receive/queue?
- If I have a **Rendezvous** Channel and it is already running something (on suspend for example, waiting API) and I `offer` a new even. This will make `offer` throws exception? Cause the channel is not receiving?

If you know any other main difference I would be glad to know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`send`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/send.html) suspends the coroutine it is invoked from while the channel being sent to is full.

`send` does not send *from* one channel *to* another one. When you invoke `send` you are sending an element **to** the channel. The channel then expects another block of code to invoke `receive` from a different coroutine.

In a `RendezvousChannel` the capacity is `0`. This means that `send` always suspends waiting for a `receive` invocation from another coroutine. If you have invoked `send` on a `RendezvousChannel` and then use `offer`, [`offer`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/offer.html) will not throw an exception (it only does if the channel is closed), but rather it will return `false` if no balancing `receive` has been invoked on the `RendezvousChannel` after your initial `send`. This is because `offer` tries to immediately add the element to the channel if it doesn't violate its capacity restrictions.

Comment: This is what make me confused `Throws an exception if the channel [is closed for `send`][isClosedForSend] (see [close] for details).`  if there is no receiver and have already something trying to go in (send suspended) would be the channel `closeForSend` ? 

Thanks. And sorry to re-ask, I wanna bring the doc words

Comment: As you can see from the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/is-closed-for-send.html): "Returns true if this channel was closed by an invocation of close". A channel that is full is not closed for send.